# How to scroll to a specific table row in PySimpleGUI, so that the row is in the "middle" of the displayed table

Tags: window, pysimplegui

In the question "How to scroll to a specific table row in PySimpleGUI" (answered 3 years ago)
there is an answer:
window['-TABLE_O-'].Widget.see(99)

But how can I ask, where is the "scroll (see) position" right now?

Reason:
I want to scroll to the row, so that the row is in the "middle" of the displayed table.
If the original scroll points to a lower row, I add num_rows/2 to the value, but if the scroll points to a higher row, I have to subtract the num_rows/2

Naturally I have to take in account the len(list)

Thanks for help

I am not very experienced in using classes, so I probably should know, how to generally examine the properties - providing I had access to the documentation. I am just learning by reading code in answers and hints. But if there is a general way of getting this information, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the boundary condition to decide scroll from top or bottom to which item shown on the view of Table element.

There's tkinter method to see item, but none for `sg.Table` or `sg.Tree`.

> .see(iid)
>
> This method ensures that the item specified by iid is visible. Any of its ancestors that are closed are opened. The widget is scrolled, if necessary, so that the item appears.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['Column 0', 'Column 1']
data = [[f"({row:0>2d}, {col})" for col in range(2)] for row in range(40)]
col_widths = list(map(lambda y:max(y)+2, map(lambda x:map(len, x), zip(*data))))
num_rows = 10
offset = (num_rows + 1)//2 - 1

sg.theme('LightBlue')
layout = [
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, auto_size_columns=False, col_widths=col_widths, cols_justification='cl', display_row_numbers=True, num_rows=num_rows, key='Table'),
     sg.Listbox([i for i in range(len(data))], size=(3, 3), expand_y=True, enable_events=True, key='Listbox')],
]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)


while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Listbox":
        indexes = values[event]
        if indexes:
            index = indexes[0]
            window['Table'].update(select_rows=[index])
            if index > offset:
                index = index- offset
                window['Table'].widget.see(window['Table'].tree_ids[39])
            else:
                index = 0
                window['Table'].widget.see(window['Table'].tree_ids[0])
            iid = window['Table'].tree_ids[index]
            window['Table'].widget.see(iid)

window.close()
```

[image]